# Import and Read csv using pyspark in Sagemaker Studio - JAVA_HOME is not set PySparkRuntimeError

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am getting Java runtime error when I try to import and read CSV in S3 using pyspark in Sagemaker Studio. Can anyone help?

https://github.com/rog-SARTHAK/AWS-Sagemaker-Studio/blob/main/Crime.ipynb

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CrimeInsights").getOrCreate()
```

It gives me JAVA_HOME is not set error:

```
JAVA_HOME is not set

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PySparkRuntimeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 1
----> 1 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CrimeInsights").getOrCreate()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py:497, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    495     sparkConf.set(key, value)
    496 # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 497 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    498 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    499 # by all sessions.
    500 session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py:515, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    513 with SparkContext._lock:
    514     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 515         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    516     assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    517     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py:201, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls, memory_profiler_cls)
    195 if gateway is not None and gateway.gateway_parameters.auth_token is None:
    196     raise ValueError(
    197         "You are trying to pass an insecure Py4j gateway to Spark. This"
    198         " is not allowed as it is a security risk."
    199     )
--> 201 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    202 try:
    203     self._do_init(
    204         master,
    205         appName,
   (...)
    215         memory_profiler_cls,
    216     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py:436, in SparkContext._ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    434 with SparkContext._lock:
    435     if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 436         SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    437         SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    439     if instance:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py:107, in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    104     time.sleep(0.1)
    106 if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 107     raise PySparkRuntimeError(
    108         error_class="JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED",
    109         message_parameters={},
    110     )
    112 with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:
    113     gateway_port = read_int(info)

PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.
``
```

Comment: Any progress on that? Got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the underlying issue is related to the setup and compatibility between PySpark, Java and the SageMaker environment. I would start by correctly setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variables.